# Catalina issue with creating multiple instances of Apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat7, tomcat8, catalina

I've installed two instances of `Apache Tomcat` (7 & 8) in `Windows7-64 bit`, of course with different ports and in two separate drives.  Both instances are running as expected.

I'm not sure with the `catalina` path variables, because I've set the `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` in the environment variables which are pointing to `tomcat7` instance. As the environment variables are common, I guess `tomcat8` instance must be using the same variables.

My question is do I need to configure `CATALINA_HOME` & `CATALINA_BASE` paths separately for both instances in `catalina.bat`, `startup` and `shutdown` files in `tomcat8\bin` directory.

Comment: I think if such variables are designed, use it properly. Maybe in simpler situation aren't important (can be unset) - my personal think, not realize. Else set correctly, For real bigger Tomcat project path to structure is important.